# Remove special characters and numbers in a number string

Tags: excel, filter, excel-formula, concatenation, substitution

I would like to cleanup some string that contains special characters and numbers.

I tried some formula in achieving this with a string that contains letters and numbers:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(C2,"0",""),"1",""),"2",""),"3",""),"4",""),"5",""),"6",""),"7",""),"8",""),"9",""),";#;#",", "),";#","")
```

[image: Example 1]

However, my main problem here is that I would like to clean up a string which contains numbers as shown below:

[image: Example 2]

Is there anyway I can achieve the above screenshot by tweaking the formula I used for the first example? As the formula in the first example would only delete all the characters in the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting challenge, and it might be done smarter/shorter, but I wanted to give it a try using formulas only (another option I could think of is using PowerQuery):

---

So bascially in `B2` put:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,TEXT(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A2,";#","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[string-length(text())>3]"),"0000"))
```

---

***Results:***

[image]

---

> **Note:** It's an array formula and needs to be confirmed through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

And untill MS introduces some sort of `SPLIT` formula to the DA-formula family I think `FILTERXML` is going to be your best bet.

Comment: Thank you JvdV! This is what I am looking for. It works great!

Comment: Yes, very interesting indeed. I should be familiarizing myself with XPATH. Thanks for the help and being informative! :)

Comment: Can I ask another question? :) An example would be for 1870;#92;#2165;#32;#1276;#94 -- I changed it to 1870;#192;#2165;#132;#1276;#194 and gave me different result. The only consistent in this string are the 1870,2165,1276 which contains 4. I adjusted the formula to >4 but it gave me an error.

Comment: Got it already. Forgot to replace formula with the updated answer. My bad. Thanks again, JvdV! :)

Comment: Note that you can still check for the exact length if that is what you require @Sevpoint. `"//s[string-length(text())=4]"`. Let's clean up the comment section =)